Setting an Api Key in dart-dio openapi generated code
I've created an API using openapi-generator-cli and using the dart-dio generator.
My Api needs an apikey header with an API set.
Currently, I can get data from the api if I set the apikey header on each api call:
final api = Openapi().getMakesApi();
...
future: api.apiListitemsMakessGet(headers: {'apikey': 'ABC123'}),

This works fine and I can get data. However I want to set the ApiKey at global level, and have tried the following which don't work.
Openapi().setApiKey('apikey', 'ABC123');
final api = Openapi().getMakesApi();
...
future: api.apiListitemsMakessGet();

final apiClient = Openapi();
apiClient.setApiKey('apikey', 'ABC123');
final api = apiClient.getMakesApi();
...
future: api.apiListitemsMakessGet();

and making a new interceptor:
ApiKeyAuthInterceptor apiKeyAuthInterceptor = ApiKeyAuthInterceptor();
apiKeyAuthInterceptor.apiKeys
    .addAll({'apikey': 'ABC123'});

var a = Openapi();
a.dio.interceptors.add(apiKeyAuthInterceptor);
final api = a.getMakesApi();
...
future: api.apiListitemsMakessGet();

All of these have the same result of not passing the apikey header to the request.
What should I be doing?

I am not sure which package you use. Could you try with this code snippet?
ApiKeyAuthInterceptor apiKeyAuthInterceptor = ApiKeyAuthInterceptor(
    onRequest: (RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
        options.headers['apikey'] = 'ABC123';
        return handler.next(options);
    },
);

